# Parallel exceution in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have three functions. Just like the sample given below.

```
function1 {

  // Do some validation

}
function2 {

 // Do some read and write operations in DB

}
function3 {

 // Do some parallel task

}
```

How can I execute all the three functions parallel in nodejs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631774/coordinating-parallel-execution-in-node-js

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631774/coordinating-parallel-execution-in-node-js)

Answer (score 3):

You can use fork, as comments above suggest, or easier still use the async package from [caolan](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the functions do.

If they all use asynchronous I/O, you can simply call them so each can start that I/O, which will run in parallel.

```
function1();
function2();
function3();
```

> Note: If you need to coordinate their completions, then you'll want to look into [flow control](https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/flow%20control) libraries such as [`async`](https://npmjs.org/package/async) or [`q`](https://npmjs.org/package/q).

But, if any of them are synchronous, then it gets trickier. You'll need to introduce asynchronous I/O around each of them. This can possibly be done through [`cluster`s](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or [`child_process`](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to start multiple `node` processes.

But, it can't be done in JavaScript alone. JavaScript is still single-threaded with Node, so synchronous tasks will block other JavaScript code from executing. Asynchronous I/O is possible only through [native C/C++ binaries](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html) using [`libuv`](https://github.com/joyent/libuv).