# running a task in parallel in nodejs

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing

This seems to work:

```
function callLoop (n) {
  function caller () {
    console.log("hello from " + n);
    setTimeout(function () {
      caller();
    }, 10000);
  }

  caller();
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  callLoop(i);
}
```

setTimeout, in this example, would instead be a long-running network call. Is this the "correct" way to parallelize these network calls?

Comment: [check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631774/coordinating-parallel-execution-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`async.parallel`](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel):

```
var async = require( 'async' );

function callLoop (n) {
  function caller () {
    console.log("hello from " + n);
    setTimeout(function () {
      caller();
    }, 10000);
  }

  caller();
}

var functions = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  functions.push(callLoop.bind(null, i));
}

async.parallel(functions);
```

Comment: the example you have will terminate, whereas my example will not (this is what I want). Also, i'm not looping for the sake of an example, I actually want to execute the same code multiple times. And finally, I don't care about "synchronizing" them (i.e. waiting for them to all finish) and then doing something.

Comment: As far as "synchronizing", the last `callback` is optional. The first argument is an array of functions, which you could construct with your for loop.

Comment: I updated the code. Let me know if that is what you were thinking.