# validate multiple ajax call complete successfully in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

In my application i'am making two ajax call for getting some data from database based on another variable value.
code part:

```
var xmlHttp;
var redirect;

function populate_site(obj, passedselect) {
    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

    var site_type;

    if (obj.value) {
        site_type = obj.value
    }else {
        site_type = document.app.site_type.value;
    }

    var url="/cgi-bin/Web/Begin.cgi";
    url=url+"?redirect=Get_Site_List";
    url=url+"&site_type=" + site_type;

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);    
}

function stateChanged() {     
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){ 
        document.getElementById('site_id').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
}

function Populate_Process_List(obj, process_id_param) {    
    var action_id;

    if (obj.value) {
        action_id = obj.value
    }else {
        action_id = document.app.action_id.value;
    }

    xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject();

    if (obj.value == '') {
        document.getElementById('process_id').innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
        return false;
    }

    var url="/cgi-bin/Web/Begin.cgi";
    url=url+"?redirect=Fetch_User_Process_List";
    url=url+"&action_id=" + action_id;
    url=url+"&process_id=" + process_id_param;
    url=url+"&gp_flag=" + 'YES';                                         
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= Process_Data_StateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);        
}

function Process_Data_StateChanged() {
    if(xmlHttp.responseText != 'NA') {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById('process_id').innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    var xmlHttp1=null;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp1=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        // Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp1=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp1=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp1;
}
```

And validating `site_id` and `process_id` variable using JavaScript.

Problem facing is whenever user press the submit button before ajax call loading is not completed (since me passing async parameter of the `open()` method has as `true`). Even while validating the `site_id` and `process_id` variable using JavaScript is not getting captured.

Validation code:

```
var siteaddindex = document.app.site_id[document.app.site_id.selectedIndex].value;

if(siteaddindex == "null"){
    alert("Please select site location.");
    document.app.site_id.focus();
    return false;
}

var process_id = document.app.process_id.value;

if (process_id == '') {
    alert("Please select process");
    return false;
}
```

Please let me know how to perform validation of above fields, since those fields are mandatory.

Comment: I only skimmed the question, but have you considered using promises?

Comment: Enable the button only after load complete

Comment: Since in my programming having two ajax calls, how can i come to know whether both ajax calls are loaded completely. so that i can enable the button for submission.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4631774/coordinating-parallel-execution-in-node-js/4631909?s=8|3.9164#4631909

Comment: Note that these days there is a library, async.js, that implements the answer I've given above + more ways for you to control these sort of things.