# How to prevent multiple http requests from firing all at once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have an array of objects. For each object I need to trigger an asynchronous request (http call). But I only want to have a certain maximum of requests running at the same time. Also, it would be nice (but not neccessary) if I could have one single synchronization point after all requests finished to execute some code.

I've tried suggestions from:

[Limit number of requests at a time with RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535685/limit-number-of-requests-at-a-time-with-rxjs/34535954#34535954)

[How to limit the concurrency of flatMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26111037/how-to-limit-the-concurrency-of-flatmap/26126750#26126750)

[Fire async request in parallel but get result in order using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34486932/fire-async-request-in-parallel-but-get-result-in-order-using-rxjs)

and many more... I even tried making my own operators.

Either the answers on those pages are too old to work with my code or I can't figure out how to put everything together so all types fit nicely.

This is what I have so far:

```js
for (const obj of objects) {
  this.myService.updateObject(obj).subscribe(value => {
    this.anotherService.set(obj);
  });
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
Ok, I think we're getting there! With the answers of *Julius* and *pschild* (both seem to work equally) I managed to limit the number of requests. But now it will only fire the first batch of 4 and never fire the rest. So now I have:

```
const concurrentRequests = 4;
from(objects)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(obj => this.myService.updateObject(obj), concurrentRequests),
    tap(result => this.anotherService.set(result))
  ).subscribe();
```

Am I doing something wrong with the `subscribe()`?

Btw: The `mergeMap` with `resultSelector` parameter is deprecated, so I used `mergeMap` without it.
Also, the `obj` of the `mergeMap` is not visible in the `tap`, so I had to use `tap`'s parameter

**EDIT 2:**

Make sure your observers complete! (It cost me a whole day)

Comment: Yes, you're right with the deprecation :-) I updated my answer accordingly. Could you have a look at my example at Stackblitz? I cannot reproduce the errors you got... maybe you could also create an example showing the errors?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem in Stackblitz. I don't think it has anything to do with angular/electron/nodejs... at least I hope.
Anyway here is a Stackblitz which is more similar to my code:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dawwsl?file=index.ts](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-dawwsl?file=index.ts)

I swear I checked the code character for character, but still..
The only thing I can say is that my code doesn't hit the finalize method. But the first 4 requests all go through the pipe nicely.

Comment: Oh and also, there are no errors on the console. How can I find out where and why it's stuck? I've tried with the `catchError` operator - no luck.

Comment: I think I'm losing my mind..
I copied the stackblitz code into my app and it works... so I can rule out my stack electron/angular etc.
I've created another stackblitz which comes even closer to my code:
[https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-yf1cik](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7-master-yf1cik)
And I've tried the error function inside the `subscribe` method... nothing

Comment: So you're saying the last Stackblitz you provided works (it does for me), but in your real code it doesn't? I think there has to be another explanation for this behaviour and so I guess that there simply is no runtime error to catch with `catchError` or the `error` function within the `subscribe`. Do you use the same versions of `rxjs`? What happens if you play around with `concurrentRequests`, set it to 1 or 100? It's hard to tell but there needs to be some difference between your two code bases.

Comment: I've figured it out! The issue was that my observer which I created in the service method never completed. Your of(..) observer completed, of course, that's why it was working. So I added `observer.complete()` and voila! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the third parameter of [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to limit the number of concurrent inner subscriptions. Use [`finalize`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html) to execute something after all requests finished:

```
const concurrentRequests = 5;
from(objects)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(obj => this.myService.updateObject(obj), concurrentRequests),
        tap(res => this.anotherService.set(res))),
        finalize(() => console.log('Sequence complete'))
    );
```

See the example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-b9rpdc).

Answer (score 2):

```
from(objects).pipe(
  bufferCount(10),
  concatMap(objs => forkJoin(objs.map(obj => 
    this.myService.updateObject(obj).pipe(
      tap(value => this.anotherService.set(obj))
  )))),
  finalize(() => console.log('all requests are done'))
)
```

*Code is not tested, but you get the idea. Let me know if any error or explanation is needed*

Comment: Your answer probably would have worked too, but I liked pschild's approach a little more.

Comment: Totally agree - wasn't aware that `mergeMap` has `concurrent` prop

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once. When I tried to load multiple images from server. I had to send http requests one after another. I achieved desired outcome using awaited promise. Here is the sample code:

```
async ngOnInit() {
    for (const number of this.numbers) {
      await new Promise(resolve => {
        this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${number}`).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.responses.push(data);
            console.log(data);
            resolve();
          }
        );
      });
    }
  }
```

Main idea is here to resolve the promise once you get the response.
With this technique you can come up with custom logic to execute one method once all the requests finished.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-http?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts). Open up the console to see it in action. :)

Comment: it's not good practice to use Promises anymore. Even if you have a promise, should be converted to an Observable

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to use operators to understand them better.